# Cleanup on navigate away

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

I'm developing an ASP.NET web application.
When a user loads a specific page on server side I start a background worker thread that captures some images from a webcam.
When the user navigates away from that specific page, I want to stop the capture (release the resources).

Is there a simple way to do it without involving jQuery? Maybe a postback could be implemented?
Thanks.

Comment: It will never be reliable so you'll need timeout handling. And the bgw is useless in ASP.NET.

Comment: @Henk Holterman why do you say it's useless? I found it works. The most important is to set IsBackground = true.

Comment: IsBackground is already true. But the Bgw is for WinForms/WPF, not ASP.NET.

Comment: What do you want to do when the user closes the browser? Or logs out? Or turns off the computer?

Comment: @John Saunders I have a worker thread on server side that should fetch some images (using a relatively large amount of resources). I want to stop the worker thread when the user navigates away from the page that displays the images.

Comment: My point is that cleaning up is going to be a lot harder if the client computer is turned off. "Navigate away" is the wrong way to think about this (and so is having a worker thread in an ASP.NET application).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not do an AJAX post back every so often (say 20 secs) and if the background thread hasn't seen a post back from that specific page in 2x as long as your post back interval (40 secs) then you close down and release the resources.  This way you will be able to handle all sorts of different ways a person can navigate away from the page such as opening a new page, closing the browser, etc.

Comment: Not a bad idea after all, but is there another solution to avoid so many postbacks? The user might stay hours on that page...

Comment: If a user is sat on a page for hours with a web cam streaming to the server are a few (or even many) ajax calls going to make a big difference?

Comment: You could easily extend the time out to not have so many post backs based on the amount of time you are willing to have your resources tied up.  Without some sort of post back there really isn't a way to know if the user is still on the page or has navigated away.